# How to check if a variable is an integer?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm using Inno Setup and want to check with Pascal Script if a string variable is an Integer (0-9 only, no hex). I have made this funcion:

```
function IsInt(s: string): boolean;
var
  i, len: Integer;
begin
  len := length(s);

  if len = 0 then
    result := false
  else
  begin
    result := true;
    for i := 1 to len do
    begin
      if not (s[i] in ['0'..'9']) then  !!! ERROR HERE !!!
      begin
        result := false;
        exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

But the compiler raises an error:

```
Closing square bracket (']') expected.
```

How to fix it?

If I change the line to this:

```
  if not (s[i] in ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']) then
```

It complies but if the code is executed it gives this error:

```
Runtime Error - Invalid Type.
```

What to do?

Comment: Looks like you want to check if a `String` is a `Number`, not `Integer`. Am I right? Because you don't need it to Return True when it passes a HEX Number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using sets you could just do a simple range test, e.g.

```
IF (s[i] < '0') OR (s[i] > '9') THEN
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Pascal script documentation

> Prototype: function StrToIntDef(s: string; def: Longint): Longint;
>
> Description: The StrToInt function converts the string passed in S
>   into a number. If S does not represent a valid number, StrToInt
>   returns the number passed in Def.

so set def to -1 and if your string is not a number it will return -1.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need. Only digits from 0 to 9 should be accepted as an integer. StrToIntDef accepts Hex too: StrToIntDef('$1E', 0) will give 30. Anyway, the function is usefull for other use-cases.