Inno Setup Closing square bracket (']') expected
I wonder why Inno Setup is complaining about:
if not ((ProductKeyPage.Values[1][i] in ['a'..'f']) or (ProductKeyPage.Values[1][i] in ['A'..'F']) or (ProductKeyPage.Values[1][i] in ['0'..'9'])) then

It's telling me the column is just after the 'a' (where the first dot of .. starts).
I haven't done Pascal in a while, but I think it looks correct?
Any ideas?
TIA!!

It is valid Object Pascal, but Inno Setup evidently has problems with sets of characters like that. You might get some mileage out of just writing a helper function to return whether or not the character represents is a hexadecimal digit. (Been a while since I’ve messed with Inno, dunno what character classification routines exist or if  you need to just write your own.)

What about adopting the logic in the accepted answer here?https://stackoverflow.com/a/24120249/2287576

FYI: If you are unsure about braces you can use Visual Studio 2005 - 2022 (with Inno support) to highlight matching/missing brace pair. But see also other answers: you may need to rewrite your code.
